# Does Adobe TLF Support Chinese Fonts in RichEditableText Component

Tags: flash, apache-flex, fonts, cjk, tlf

I've created a "Poster Maker" in Flex. The text part of the poster is written inside a TLF-based RichEditableText component. Users can choose the font for the text using a ComboBox which lists all the device fonts on the computer.

All works well, until Chinese users try to apply a Chinese font and it doesn't work.

Here's a [screencast of the problem](http://www.screenr.com/zZ5) (just over 1 min long). In it you can see I can write Chinese in WordPad and apply the two different Chinese fonts I have on the PC without any problems. When I switch to the Flex app and try the same it doesn't work.

I'm at a loss as to why this won't work.

The change event of the font picker ComboBox looks like this:

```
var txtLayFmt:TextLayoutFormat = editor.getFormatOfRange(null,
 editor.selectionAnchorPosition,
 editor.selectionActivePosition
);

txtLayFmt.fontFamily = fontPicker.selectedItem.font;

editor.setFormatOfRange(txtLayFmt,
 editor.selectionAnchorPosition,
 editor.selectionActivePosition
);
```

Where selectedItem.font is the fontname of the font and is what you see as the label in the ComboBox.

Any help is much appreciated.

Jake

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use "**AFEFontManager**" for Chinese Fonts

[About the font managers](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_06.html)

To change the font manager use compiler argument

```
-managers flash.fonts.AFEFontManager
```

EDITED:

I Agree you are using device FONTS but change FONT-MANAGER preferences may also put impact on run time

Please Try to compile APP by Change Font-Manager Order as in link

[Troubleshooting fonts in Flex applications](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_03.html)

Hopes that helps

Comment: That didn't seem to work. The page you linked to says that Flash/Flex uses font managers to deal with embedded fonts. In my case the fonts aren't embedded. They're device fonts.

Comment: did you compile app with "AFEFontManager"

Comment: Yes, I tried adding the compiler argument but it had no effect.

Comment: Plz try modifying "flex-config.xml" ck link in EDIT

Comment: I just re-ordered the font managers (put AFE to the top) in the flex-config.xml file and re-compiled. Still no change.

Comment: Plz do one more thing "embedAsCFF" i.e. lines from Blog http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/files/flexdoc/fonts.pdf --"For Spark
controls, set embedAsCFF to true. For fonts that are used by Halo controls, try setting embedAsCFF to false."---